# IOS app and firebase logging in without any error's with wrong password

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase

Here is my code

```
import UIKit
import Firebase


class LoginVC: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: RoundedCornerTextField!

@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: RoundedCornerTextField!

@IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!

@IBOutlet weak var authBtn: RoundedShadowButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    emailTextField.delegate = self
    passwordTextField.delegate = self

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    view.bindToKeyboard()

    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapHandler(sender:)))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

@IBAction func dissmissBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}

@objc func tapHandler(sender : UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

@IBAction func authBtnWasPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    //TODO : SingIn methods here

    if emailTextField.text != nil && passwordTextField.text != nil {

        authBtn.animatedButton(shouldload: true, withMessage: nil)
        self.view.endEditing(true)

        if let email = emailTextField.text, let password = passwordTextField.text {
            Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (authResult, error) in
                if error == nil {
                    if let user = authResult?.user {
                        if self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
                            let userData = ["provider": user.providerID] as [String: Any]
                            DataService.instance.createFirbaseDBUser(uid: user.uid, userData: userData, isDriver: false)

                        } else {
                            let userData = ["provider" : user.providerID, "userIsDriver" : true, "isPickUpModeEnabaled" : false , "driverIsOnTrip": false ] as [String : Any]
                            DataService.instance.createFirbaseDBUser(uid: user.uid, userData: userData, isDriver: true)
                        }
                    }
                 print("Email user authenticated with firebase")

                    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                }else {

                    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (AuthDataResult, error) in

                        if error != nil {
                            if let errorCode = AuthErrorCode(rawValue: error! ._code){

                                switch errorCode {


                                case .invalidEmail:
                                    print("wrong email")
                                case .invalidCustomToken:
                                    print ("invalid creadentials")
                                case .customTokenMismatch:
                                    print("Wrong password or emial")
                                case .invalidCredential:
                                    print("invalid credential")


                                case .userDisabled:
                                    print("unexpected error")
                                case .operationNotAllowed:
                                     print("unexpected error")
                                case .emailAlreadyInUse:
                                     print("unexpected error")
                                case .wrongPassword:
                                     print("unexpected error")
                                case .tooManyRequests:
                                     print("unexpected error")
                                case .userNotFound:
                                     print("unexpected error")
                                case .accountExistsWithDifferentCredential:
                                     print("unexpected error")
                                case .requiresRecentLogin:
                                     print("unexpected error")
                                case .providerAlreadyLinked:
                                     print("unexpected error")
                                case .noSuchProvider:
                                     print("unexpected error")
                                case .invalidUserToken:
                                     print("unexpected error")
                                case .networkError:
                                     print("unexpected error")
                                case .userTokenExpired:
                                     print("unexpected error")
                                case .invalidAPIKey:
                                     print("unexpected error")
                                case .userMismatch:
                                     print("unexpected error")
                                case .credentialAlreadyInUse:
                                     print("unexpected error")
                                case .weakPassword:
                                     print("unexpected error")
                                case .appNotAuthorized:
                                     print("unexpected error")
                                case .expiredActionCode:
                                     print("unexpected error")
                                case .invalidActionCode:
                                     print("unexpected error")
                                case .invalidMessagePayload:
                                     print("unexpected error")
                                case .invalidSender:
                                     print("unexpected error")
                                case .invalidRecipientEmail:
                                     print("unexpected error")
                                case .missingEmail:
                                     print("unexpected error")
                                case .missingIosBundleID:
                                     print("unexpected error")
                                case .missingAndroidPackageName:
                                     print("unexpected error")
                                case .unauthorizedDomain:
                                     print("unexpected error")
                                case .invalidContinueURI:
                                     print("unexpected error")
                                case .missingContinueURI:
                                     print("unexpected error")
                                case .missingPhoneNumber:
                                     print("unexpected error")
                                case .invalidPhoneNumber:
                                     print("unexpected error")
                                case .missingVerificationCode:
                                     print("unexpected error")
                                case .invalidVerificationCode:
                                     print("unexpected error")
                                case .missingVerificationID:
                                     print("unexpected error")
                                case .invalidVerificationID:
                                     print("unexpected error")
                                case .missingAppCredential:
                                     print("unexpected error")
                                case .invalidAppCredential:
                                     print("unexpected error")
                                case .sessionExpired:
                                     print("unexpected error")
                                case .quotaExceeded:
                                     print("unexpected error")
                                case .missingAppToken:
                                     print("unexpected error")
                                case .notificationNotForwarded:
                                     print("unexpected error")
                                case .appNotVerified:
                                     print("unexpected error")
                                case .captchaCheckFailed:
                                     print("unexpected error")
                                case .webContextAlreadyPresented:
                                     print("unexpected error")
                                case .webContextCancelled:
                                     print("unexpected error")
                                case .appVerificationUserInteractionFailure:
                                     print("unexpected error")
                                case .invalidClientID:
                                     print("unexpected error")
                                case .webNetworkRequestFailed:
                                     print("unexpected error")
                                case .webInternalError:
                                     print("unexpected error")
                                case .nullUser:
                                     print("unexpected error")
                                case .keychainError:
                                     print("unexpected error")
                                case .internalError:
                                     print("unexpected error")
                                case .malformedJWT:
                                     print("unexpected error")
                                }



                            }
                        }else {
                            if let user = authResult?.user {
                                if self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
                                    let userdata = ["provider" : user.providerID] as [String : Any]
                                    DataService.instance.createFirbaseDBUser(uid: user.uid, userData: userdata, isDriver: false)
                                } else {
                                    let userData = ["provider" : user.providerID, "userIsDriver" : true, "isPickUpModeEnabaled" : false , "driverIsOnTrip": false ] as [String : Any]
                                    DataService.instance.createFirbaseDBUser(uid: user.uid, userData: userData, isDriver: true)
                                }
                            }
                            print("Successfully created a new user ")
                        }

                        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil    )
                    })
                }
            }
        )}
    }

}
```

When I try to sign in with a wrong password it does log in. I don't know where I am wrong.

In my firebase console I can see user's in authentication with there UID, but when I switch to database I don't see any thing apart from the table I created manually.

Comment: After you attempt to sign in, you further move on to create a new account, which doesn't make sense to me.  By the way, the word 'loging' that you use to write the title of the topic is not an English word.

Comment: I further move to create a new account as i have put a single button for login and signup so if the user is not registered already he will get registered. well let me correct the "Logging" with Log in. Will appreciate your help

Comment: Instead of the createUser section, put a 'print' instead.  Then try your issue - you should see that instead of the log in.  That should prove that creating an account on any sort of failure is not really a great idea.... - though you could do another check against the user to see if they are valid (look in the error) and if not, then do the auto-create.  I would probably fail them to a "Hey you aren't a user, would you like to be?" page instead of creating an account, but at a minimum, look at the error and see what you can learn from it.

Comment: ok but my firebase database is not updating its showing me user's in authentication tab but not in the databse

Comment: why my data base is not updating ??